# Movimiento por teclas especificas (evento KeyPress no recibe Enter)

Tags: c#

Tengo un formulario de ventas en el cual el usuario puede ir realizando las ventas agregando items hasta que termine la venta.

Quiero que al indicarle que presione una tecla realize la accion de cambiar el atributo `enabled` de un elemento y pasarle el focus al mismo.

Esto es lo que intentado:

```
 private void ventapiezas_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))
        {
            txtefectivo.Enabled = true;
            txtefectivo.Focus();
        }

    }
```

Pero no funciona, no despliega error. `ventapiezas` es el formulario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los argumentos de **KeyPress** no informan si enter fue presionado, utiliza `KeyUp` en vez.

```
    private void ventapiezas_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {

            //Tu accion

            }
        }
```